# How to create a Patch for Rietveld by git/patch/*?

Tags: patch, rietveld

I have a file where I added a print -statement such that

```
 print "hello"         // this is a change
 ----- file -------
```

I have the change in my Git's commit tree.

I would like to have a patch which I can use for [Rietveld](http://codereview.appspot.com/).

I get the following when I have the changed file at `Data`, while the unchanged file at `Base`.

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/codepreview-patch.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/codepreview-patch.png)

**How can you make a patch which I can give for Rietveld?**

Comment: It appears that your question is related to getting pbcopy to work from within screen.  You should probably clarify the question, as I posted this by editing a file and then running '$ pbcopy < file' from within screen, so clearly bpcopy and screen work just fine together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the current state Rietveld r530 online patch parser understands only SVN based patches - no Mercurial or Git format. That's why [it is advised](http://codereview.appspot.com/use_uploadpy) to use upload.py utility for sending patches.

Comment: how to use upload.py with git patches?