# How can I convert a raw patch set from Rietveld code review to a local Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, patch, rietveld

I would like to use the "Download raw patch set" link on Rietveld code review and apply that to my working directory under Mercurial. It's clear that the "raw patch set" isn't in Mercurial format. I've always considered these formats as implementation details and have never paid attention to them. I can suppose that, per this related issue [How to create a Patch for Rietveld by git/patch/*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168268/to-create-a-patch-for-rietveld-by-git-patch/2979101), that the patch set is in SVN format, but I know little enough that I can only surmise that, but not verify it. I suppose I want something like `download.py` to do the conversion for me without having to dig down into the bowels of this issue, but such a script does not seem to exist.

As a bonus requirement, I use TortoiseHg almost exclusively, and I'd like to be able to do this within it. In particular, it would be great if the patch set automatically appeared in the shelves tool.

How do I apply the Rietveld patch set against my working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I apply the Rietveld patch set against my working directory?

Just **apply it**!

Yes, Rietveld patches are SVN-type, but Mercurial can import SVN-diffs

- Download needed raw patch set
- TortoiseHG Workbench menu bar - `Repository` - `Import`

[image: Import In TortoiseHG]

- Select needed file (files)
- **Don't forget to enable** "Do not strip paths"
- Select import target
- Test results of import

Comment: Thanks. I would not have thought to look there. I had copied the diff file into the .hg subdirectory for shelves, but it wasn't showing up. I'll chalk this up to insufficient UI analysis.